# Is it possible to specify different folder structures for 2 equivalent Git repositories?

Tags: bash, git, continuous-integration, git-bash

Some of the environments for an application that I help maintain have a folder structure which cannot currently be changed, for example:

#### Development Environment

```
Folder 1
  |--File 1
  |--File 2
```

#### Test Environment

```
Folder One
  |--File 1
  |--File 2
```

**I need to keep the folder structure as is**, but I would like to push my changes between my development and test environments as I am not currently able to restructure the folders.

I have heard Urbancode Deploy has features like this, but I'm wondering if this can be achieved with Git on its own or Git and Shell? Are there any other open source software or extensions that can help with this?

Comment: What tool do you use for CI ?

Comment: I don't think that can't be done with git only. You could use a master branch for dev with the 1st folder structure and another branch for test with the 2nd folder structure, but you'll have conflict you'd have to manually handle every time you want to merge your work

Comment: We are not currently using any CI tools, although the plan is to move to Urbancode Deploy in the medium term, I was hoping to write some scripts for automatically pushing between those folders with different names. So for example, could i stage the contents of "folder 1" in the Dev repository to "Folder One" in the Test repository?

Comment: What part is versioned ? If your git repo contains `/File 1` and `/File 2` at its root, it's simply a matter of checking out the repo in `Folder 1` on dev, and `Folder One` on test.

Comment: There is an upper level folder which is the repository (call it dev-repo and test-repo). Could a solution be adding those folder to the .gitignore file, and setting up a separate repository within the top level repository? then I could push from the "folder 1" repo to "folder One"

Answer (score 0):

First : keep in mind that `git` is a versioning tool, not a deployment tool.

`git pull` is a very handy functionnality, but it only goes so far as a deployment script.
If you need to do some extra action on deployment (such as : renaming a folder ...) you can write a simple deployment script :

```
#/bin/sh

git pull
rm -rf "Folder One"
cp -r "Folder 1" "Folder One"
```

---

Some other ways : if the target system supports symlinks, you can add a symlink in your repo :

```
ln -s "Folder 1" "Folder One"
git add "Folder One"
git commit -m "add symlink to match the expected structure on testing env"
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually UrbanCode Deploy can achieve that as you can define the properties of your environments outside of the deployment process.
F.e.

- your file and folder structure beneath FOLDER 1/ONE is a component and has a deployment process (whatever you want to achieve there, just define it once, target agnostic)
- during deployment the process queries the property of the target environment from UCD and gets Folder 1 for DEV and Folder One for TEST and does the rest to put the files and folders in the right target directory...